# Adding Todays Date / and of Month Date & Other Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure if this is possible?

I need to get the code to read

Todays month ie Feb
Todays date ie 17
End of month date ie 31
and then
the other 11 months of the years in order on one line

Aug 1 - 31 | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul

Any suggestions in the best way to do this please?

Many thanks

Tim

Comment: you might want to look into moment js or another library like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```js
const months= ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var newMonths = "";
var d = new Date();

// Find current day, month and last day of month
var currentDay = d.getDate();
var lastDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59).getDate();
var month = d.getMonth();

for (var i = month + 1; i <= 11; i++) {
    newMonths = newMonths +" | " + months[i];
}
for (var i = 0; i < month; i++) {
    newMonths = newMonths +" | " + months[i];
}

console.log(months[month] + " " + currentDay + " - " + lastDay + " " + newMonths);
```

Here is the updated jdfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k04amscv/

Comment: Thank you for that, Im not sure how I test this code? to see if it works

Comment: I added a jsfiddle in the answer to check how it works.

Comment: That is amazing, just one last question, in css I can set the colour of the main strip to black but is there away to make the month text ie 'Mar 12 - 31' to be green ?? Not sure if that is possible?

Comment: Instead of a button to load the dates of the month I want it to show straight away on the page. at the moment I have used a body tag which is totally  wrong! but is the only way I can get it to work but when I check the code I get error - body tag already open. 
Not sure which tag to use to get the code to show up. hope you can help. thanks Tim


</head>

<body>
<!-- body code goes here -->


<div class="scrollable-nav-inner">
<nav class="scrollable-nav">
<ul>
<li><a class="font" id="date"><body onload="showDate();"></body></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

Comment: @TimCross you cant use `body` tag twice. That's why you got that error. Check the jsfiddle i updated. If my answer solves your problem feel free to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: I can only see part of the code from... Const months... to NewMonths); in the code Snippet. If I take the body part of the code ie <li><a class="font" id="date"><onload="showDate();"></a></li> then it wont work. I cant see how you got to get the code to load up? thanks but it show up in your example! Tim

Comment: Just put your `onload` on the first `<body>` tag: `<body onload="showDate()"> <!-- body code goes here --> </body>`

Comment: @TimCross i added the jsfiddle to see how i trigger the function.

Comment: I was just wondering if it is possible to add links to the dates ie Aug | Sep | Nov etc or is this not possible?

I want to link this to a database so when you press another date it goes to the search data on that page but as I said I’m not sure this is possible or not??

Thanks

Tim